# Best way to get deep property in ES6 shorthand notation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am running into an issue where in I have a object as below

```
a = {
   b: {
    c: 10
   }
};
```

Now this is a dynamic object and can be empty on runtime, like this a = {}, I am trying to read c in ES6 shorthand notation like const {b: {c}} = a;. But getting error every time object is empty. Is there a way I can still use this notation for empty object, like get undefined for c in that case.

I know I can do something like (a.b ? a.b.c : undefined), but i just wanted to know shothand way of doing it.

Comment: Especially see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349521/906113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `= {}` for inner objects:

```js
const a = {
   b: {
    c: 10
   }
};

const f = ({b: {c} = {}}) => console.log(c)

f(a)
f({})
```

In this case `c` becomes undefined if the object is empty

Comment: This way even if I have value assigned to c: 10, I will always get c as undefined. isn't it?

Comment: @RanjeetGautam run my code. When `c` is defined it returns the value; otherwise undefined.

Comment: Yes sorry my apology, it does run but isn't this is like setting default property in method parameter? Actually I wanted to know simple shorthand method to capture c even when b is undefined.

Comment: @RanjeetGautam in this case this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46630023/7636961

Answer (score 2):

you can  do

```js
let a = {
   b: {
    c: 10
   }
};

let result = a && a.b && a.b.c;

console.log(result);
```

it would return the property if it is present, otherwise it would return undefined

Comment: if `a` is guaranteed to be an object, you don't need to check it, since it will always be true

Comment: @ferrybig no no no. there's no guarantee `a` is not `null`/`undefined`

Comment: The OP says in his question "Now this is a dynamic object and can be empty on runtime, like this a = {}"

Comment: @marvel308 yes this will definitely give the result & thnk you for answering. But my question is how to do it in ES6 way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want a general approach, which isn't really terse for shallow structures but saves you compiling out a static sequence of conditionals.

```
function dive (obj, pz) {
  return pz.reduce((acc, p) => {
    return obj && p in acc ? acc[p] : undefined;
  }, obj);
}
```

You can use this with arbirary depth

```
console.log(dive({a:{b:{c:[10,11,12]}}}, ['a', 'b', 'c', 1]))
```

c.f. [this demo](https://es6console.com/j8ilnovd/)

Answer (score 0):

Give `lodash` a shot:

```
lodash.get(a, 'b.c', FALLBACK_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Comment: This I have used, I was looking for ES6 way. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: It's your choice between vanilla ES6 or safe & concise Lodash.