# JS destructuring. How to deal with null or undefined values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to implement Nullable feature in [es6](/questions/tagged/es6)? I need to support the source code of my previous co-worker, who used too much destructuring feature of [es6](/questions/tagged/es6). Something like this, every where:

```
dispatch(
    loadImports(response.items.map(({ importRecord: { ['import']: importId } }) => importId))
)
```

In this example, it's possible that I may get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'import' of null` error.

I don't want to rewrite the whole destructures to regular conditions. Or if there isn't, how to deal with them, without rewriting?

UPD:

Expected version by co-worker:
https://jsbin.com/fesewiy/edit?js,console

Current version: https://jsbin.com/qirixil/edit?js,console

Comment: What would the code look like if you did rewrite it - ie what should happen if you _do_ pass in null?  Either the code block should handle it, in which case pure destructuring is wrong because it doesn't handle the null case, or it shouldn't handle it and should throw an error anyway, in which case you're left with changing your calling code to check for nulls before you pass them.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Above example could look like this with conditions: `loadImports(response.items.map((item) => item.importRecord && item.importRecord.import && item.importRecord.import.id))`

Comment: But that fundamentally changes the meaning of what the code does.  Now you allow nulls to be mapped.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Plus, find and fix them, too much time.

Comment: @JamesThorpe It's ok, if I allow nulls, backend can handle them properly.

Comment: You have to change your code anyway. As far as I know, there is no way to do it with object destructuring. But you could use an approach like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors/42349521#42349521

Comment: Your co-worker must hate you. That is an obnoxiously unmaintainable inline function.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 Updated the post

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Added samples

Comment: You might check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338466/destructure-object-only-if-its-truthy/48338661#48338661

Comment: @xurshid29 The code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390089/js-destructuring-how-to-deal-with-null-or-undefined-values?noredirect=1#comment83675825_48179897 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390089/js-destructuring-how-to-deal-with-null-or-undefined-values?noredirect=1#comment83676180_48179897 should handle the case and return expected result

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using map, you need to get some result for each item.
The best solution with minimum changes will be to use only one level of destructuring and then filter the array to stay with array of values that are not falsy.

```
dispatch(
    loadImports(response.items
        .map(({ importRecord }) => importRecord && importRecord.import)
        .filter(v => v)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the default parameter to a plain object, use `OR` operator to return either `importId` or `null`

```
arr.map(({ importRecord: { ['import']: importId } = {}}) => importId || null)
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Note, using the approach at your comment `undefined` will be returned instead of `null`.

Comment: No it won't, it will throw the same error: https://jsfiddle.net/yttzcyf1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/cg1h92Lx/

Comment: Well, we are trying with different objects as OP did not include enough code at the question to reproduce `var arr = [{importRecord: {imported:123}} ]; arr.map(({ importRecord: { import: importId } = { import: null }}) => importId)`

Comment: OP included the error, which indicates that `importRecord` is sometimes `null`, not `undefined`.

Comment: "In this example, it's possible that I may get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'import' of null` error." -- implying that the parent object of `import` which is `importRecord` is nullable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Then what is the object? Cannot reproduce that exact error.

Comment: Again, see https://jsfiddle.net/yttzcyf1/ The "exact" error message is browser-dependent, but the cause is the same.

Comment: That is not the _exact_ same error as described at OP. Did you cast "downvote" for an answer to a question where the code is not reproduced at OP?

Comment: Did you prematurely answer a question that wasn't MCVE?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No. Tested code around 11-20-2017. Unfortunately did not preserve the object that tested with the code at Answer. Would have to scan the drive (time consuming) to rebuild the code tried around the date that made a note of the Question to get the objects tried at that time, though will try anyway. Would not have posted unless the code returned expected result

Comment: Note that my implication was that if the question is not MCVE, the answer is by definition premature. It doesn't matter whether or not you tested your code. As you've stated, you're still unsure what the conditions to produce OP's error were, therefore writing an answer you're certain is correct is impossible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, was not premature as to the interpretation of the Question at the time. Again, else, would not have posted the Answer two months later. Am trying to avoid the time consuming process of filtering through the fragments in hd to contend with your assessment of what the code at OP is. Note, that your point is plausible, though you too are working from the standpoint of speculation. It may have been that interpreted the question at the time as to `import` property being null. Usually keep such tests, though did not on this occasion.

Comment: Again, as _you've_ just stated, you gave `an answer to a question where the code is not reproduced at OP`. That is not MCVE. Therefore, said `interpretation of the question at the time` is not 100% certain. This is the risk of interpretation. I've given you mine, and based on mine, this answer is incorrect. Accept your -2 with a little dignity and just move on.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It is not about "dignity". That is a feeling that is irrelevant, and no external entity could possibly effect this users' state of being whatsoever. Am concerned with the code itself. It does not matter whether the "downvote" is "accepted" or not. You already did what you did. Will try to find the code that tried which prompted the Answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ah, was coding for `import` not being defined `[{importRecord: {abc:123}} ].map(({ importRecord: { ['import']: importId } = {}}) => importId || null)`

Comment: That's a non-representative test-case since `[{importRecord: {abc:123}} ].map(({ importRecord: { ['import']: importId } }) => importId)` doesn't throw a `TypeError` as OP has indicated can occur with input.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Missed including the `s` in the last comment `var arr = [{importRecords: null} ]; arr.map(({ importRecord: { ['import']: importId } = {}}) => importId || null)`. Here is the code which logs same error as described at OP  `arr.map(({ importRecord: { ['import']: importId } }) => importId)` given the `arr` above

Comment: That handles the case for `importRecord === undefined` but now we're back to the start where I said you don't handle `importRecord === null` as OP's `TypeError` indicates.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts What are you talking about now? `importRecord` does not exist, which is also a viable interpretation of the question. Note that cannot reproduce the _exact_ error described at OP. The error is always `'undefined' or 'null'`. OP does not explicitly state that `importRecord` _is_ `null`. The same error is thrown for either case. And there is nothing that you could surmise from the original question which would distinguish between the two possibilities and settle the matter. OP needs to reproduce the code to settle the matter of which pattern returns which error

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Therefore, your "downvote" is unwarranted given the examples demonstrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390089/js-destructuring-how-to-deal-with-null-or-undefined-values/48179897?noredirect=1#comment83674615_48179897. You cannot conclusively draw the conclusion that this users' interpretation of the original question is incorrect. Though your interpretation of the question is duly noted and also viable. Perhaps post your own answer to the inquiry so resolve all possible cases.

Comment: "`importRecord` does not exist" satisfies `importRecord === undefined`. You should know this. Also, I take it you're using Chrome. In recent versions, Chrome has used a more generic message for destructuring errors, e.g. ``TypeError: Cannot destructure property `import` of 'undefined' or 'null'.``. However you can still reproduce specific cases from 2 or 3 versions ago by simply attempting `null.import` or `undefined.import`. Your argument that it cannot be reproduced _exactly_ holds no water, you're just refusing to acknowledge your answer does not solve the original problem.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Am not refusing to acknowledge anything. We simply interpreted the question differently. Sustain the "downvote" if that satisfies to match your critique of the answer. Though you cannot refute that the answer does in fact handle the case of `importRecord` not existing in the first instance, as demonstrated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390089/js-destructuring-how-to-deal-with-null-or-undefined-values/48179897?noredirect=1#comment83674615_48179897. Your perspective lends another case to the inquiry which did not consider at the time. You should post your own answer.

Comment: OP's error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'import' of null` cannot possibly occur in _any_ implementation of JavaScript when the condition "`importRecord` does not exist" occurs, otherwise the error would be `TypeError: Cannot read property 'import' of undefined` or ``TypeError: Cannot destructure property `import` of 'undefined' or 'null'.`` depending on the implementation. Your interpretation is incorrect. Period.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ok, let us take a step back. What are you suggesting is the object which creates the error?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This should handle that case `[{ importRecord: null }].map(({importRecord} = {}) => { let {import:importId} = importRecord || {}; return importId}) // [undefined]`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Any objections or considerations not seeing here as to the above pattern?

Comment: No objections, though it does return `undefined` instead of `null`. I thought you wanted it to return `null`. Just to clarify, that's not an objection, just an observation. Also an equivalent to your above suggestion would be `[{ importRecord: null }].map(({importRecord} = {}) => (importRecord || {}).import)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Independent observations as to code posted at answer are certainly welcome here. Where does OP specify what should be returned for that case?

Comment: OP does not specify, that's why I explicitly stated it wasn't an objection. I just observed that your current answer prefers to output `null` [like you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390089/js-destructuring-how-to-deal-with-null-or-undefined-values/48179897?noredirect=1#comment83673194_48179897).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Now OP has solutions for at least two cases. That is, if the actual code reflects what is currently described at the original question.