# destructure object only if it's truthy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I want to destructure my function argument like this

```
const func = ({field: {subField}}) => subField;
```

How can I prevent this from throwing an error if field is `undefined` or `null` ?

Comment: const func = ({field: subField}) => subField;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might use a default value:

```
const func = ({field: {subField} = {}}) => subField;
```

It works only with `{field: undefined}` though, not with `null` as a value. For that I'd just use

```
const func = ({field}) => field == null ? null : field.subField;
// or if you don't care about getting both null or undefined respectively
const func = ({field}) => field && field.subField;
```

See also [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/1048572) for general solutions.

Comment: or  `func = ({field}) => (field || {}).subField;`

Answer (score 2):

You could only part destruction and use for `subField` a parameter with a check.

```js
var fn = ({ field }, subField = field && field.subField) => subField;

console.log(fn({ field: null }));
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to fix both the cases of null and undefined is the following

```
const func = ({field}) => {
   let subField = null;
   if(field) {
       ({subField} = field);
   }
   return subField
};
```

If you only want to handle the case when field is undefined, you could just to

```
const func = ({field: {subField} = {}}) => subField;
```

whereby if `field` is `undefined` the default empty object is used as its value

Comment: `const subField`?