# How to handle calling functions on data that may be undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I primarily work with React and often find that when I write a function that relies on a component's state, I have to perform a check to see if the piece of state is defined before performing any actions.

For example: I have a function that uses `.map()` to loop over an array of objects fetched from a database and generates jsx for each object in the array. This function is called in the `render()` function of my component. The first time `render()` is called, the initial array is empty. This results in an error because, of course, the first index of the array is undefined.

I have been circumventing this by making a conditional check to see if the value of the array is undefined or not. This process of writing an if statement each time feels a little clumsy and I was wondering if there is a better way to perform this check or a way to avoid it entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the array before using map:

```
arr && arr.map()
```

OR,

```
arr && arr.length && arr.map() // if you want to map only if not empty array
```

OR,

We can even use like this (as commented by [devserkan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7060441/devserkan)):

```
(arr || []).map()
```

---

As per your comment:

> I wish there was a safe navigation operator like with C# (arr?.map())

Yes, obviously. This is called [optional chaining](https://github.com/TC39/proposal-optional-chaining) in JavaScript which is still in proposal. If it is accepted, then you may use like this:

```
arr?.map()
```

You can see it in [staging 1](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) for which you may use [babel preset stage1](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-1)

---

But obviously, except the checking array length, your requirement will not be fulfilled:

> This results in an error because, of course, the first index of the array is undefined.

So, I suggest you to use:

```
arr && arr.length && arr.map()
```

Comment: I wish there was a safe navigation operator like with C# (`arr?.map()`)

Comment: Wow, optional chaining is nice. For this question how about `( arr || [] ).map`?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need here is called **optional chaining**:

```
obj?.a?.b?.c // no error if a, b, or c don't exist or are undefined/null
```

The `?.` is the existential operator and it allows you to access properties safely and won't throw if the property is missing. However optional chaining is **not yet part of JavaScript** but has been proposed and is in stage 3, [see State 3 of TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

But, using proxies and a [`Maybe`](https://medium.com/@yyankowski/maybe-monad-in-javascript-to-save-us-from-the-hell-of-the-null-guard-clauses-bc9f9a1f291b) class, you can implement optional chaining and return a default value when the chain fails.

A `wrap()` function is used to wrap objects on which you want to apply optional chaining. Internally, `wrap` creates a Proxy around your object and manages missing values using a `Maybe` wrapper.

At the end of the chain, you unwrap the value by chaining `getOrElse(default)` with a default value which is returned when the chain is not valid:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: [4, 1, 2]
  },
  c: () => 'yes'
};

console.log(wrap(obj).a.getOrElse(null)) // returns 1
console.log(wrap(obj).a.b.c.d.e.f.getOrElse(null)) // returns null
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([])) // returns [4, 1, 2]
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[0].getOrElse(null)) // returns 4
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[100].getOrElse(-1)) // returns -1
console.log(wrap(obj).c.getOrElse(() => 'no')()) // returns 'yes'
console.log(wrap(obj).d.getOrElse(() => 'no')()) // returns 'no'

wrap(obj).noArray.getOrElse([1]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 1
wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 4, 1, 2
```

The complete example:

```js
class Maybe {
  constructor(value) {
    this.__value = value;
  }
  static of(value){
    if (value instanceof Maybe) return value;
    return new Maybe(value);
  }
  getOrElse(elseVal) {
    return this.isNothing() ? elseVal : this.__value;
  }
  isNothing() {
    return this.__value === null || this.__value === undefined;
  }
  map(fn) {  
    return this.isNothing()
      ? Maybe.of(null)
      : Maybe.of(fn(this.__value));
  }
}

function wrap(obj) {
  function fix(object, property) {
    const value = object[property];
    return typeof value === 'function' ? value.bind(object) : value;
  }
  return new Proxy(Maybe.of(obj), {
    get: function(target, property) {
      if (property in target) {
          return fix(target, property);
      } else {
        return wrap(target.map(val => fix(val, property)));
      }
    }
  });
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: { c: [4, 1, 2] }, c: () => 'yes' };

console.log(wrap(obj).a.getOrElse(null))
console.log(wrap(obj).a.b.c.d.e.f.getOrElse(null))
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([]))
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[0].getOrElse(null))
console.log(wrap(obj).b.c[100].getOrElse(-1))
console.log(wrap(obj).c.getOrElse(() => 'no')())
console.log(wrap(obj).d.getOrElse(() => 'no')())

wrap(obj).noArray.getOrElse([1]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 1
wrap(obj).b.c.getOrElse([]).forEach(v => console.log(v)) // Shows 4, 1, 2
```

Comment: 2019 Update: Optional Chaining proposal is now in stage 3!