# Simplify simple ternary expression

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I want to validate undefined attributes from an object so I use ternary like this

```
item.subitem ? item.subitem.toString() : ''
```

Is there any way to simplify this expression using `||` or `&&` ?

Comment: I usually have `const string = value => value == null? "": String(value);` defined somewhere in my code, among a few others. Then it's just `string(item.subitem);`

Comment: that's a nice way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple:

```
item.subitem && item.subitem.toString() || ''
```

Or simply like:

```
(item.subitem || '').toString()
```

OR,

```
''+(item.subitem || '')
```

---

If you can use optional chaining, then it can be even more simple:

```
item.subitem?.toString()
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633568/how-to-handle-calling-functions-on-data-that-may-be-undefined/52633611#52633611) for more detail.

---

As [@Thomas mentioned in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54860214/simplify-simple-ternary-expression/54860226?noredirect=1#comment96594731_54860226), you can also use an array and convert to a string:

```
[item.subitem].toString();
```

This should clear how it will work:

```
[].toString(); // ''
[undefined].toString(); // ''
['foo'].toString(); // 'foo'
['foo', 'bar'].toString(); 'foo,bar'
```

Comment: The first example uses more bytes than the code at the question.

Comment: Yeah, but I have just provided it for OP curiosity.

Comment: when we're already at hacks do you know this one: `""+[item.subitem]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

```
(item.subitem || '').toString()
```