# Dynamic variable access in JS ES6

Tags: javascript

I am currently writing a compare function for js's Array.prototype.sort(). The question now is: I have an object instance `a` with both variables and functions I want to sort after. I learned yesterday that I can access functions (I have the method name of) like this `a['fct']()`.

So what I would like to do is something like

> `a['fct'] (typeof a['fct'] === 'function' ? () : nothing)`

So I basically want to execute it if it's a function and just use it as a variable if it's a variable. I would like to omit a whole block with the same sorting logic, so I would like to keep it with the ternary operator style. Is this possible?

Comment: `typeof a['fct'] === 'function' ? a['fct']() : a['fct']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like:

```
typeof a["fct"] == "function" ? a["fct"]() : a["fct"]
```

---

You may also use optional chaining as in [my other answer how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633611/2138752) like:

```
a["fct"]?.()
```

This will call method if `a["fct"]` is a function else result from `a["fct"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much - I was looking for something more like the second, and overlooking the obvious first option. :D