# Destructuring nested params, undefined error

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I keep getting `payload` `undefined` when destructuring:

```
let videosArray = [];
if (payload.videos) {
  const {
    payload: { videos }
  } = action;
  videosArray = videos;
}

return videosArray;
```

How can I check for undefined? I have tried the check below, but keep getting the error:

```
   if (typeof payload !== "undefined") {
```

Comment: where is `payload` declared?

Comment: do you have `payload` or `action`?

Comment: try ```if(payload){//something}```

Comment: Are you getting the error in `if (payload.videos)` or in destructuring? What is the exact error message? It's not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make sure the action is defined first, and access its parameters instead of calling payload by itself. In your example it looks as if `payload` was undeclared when you try to access it

```js
function getVideos(action) {
  if (action && action.payload && action.payload.videos) {
    const {payload: {videos}} = action;
    return videos;
  }

  return [];
}

console.log(getVideos()); // action undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({})); // payload undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({payload: {}})); // videos undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({payload: {videos: [1,2,3]}})); // expected [1,2,3]
```

Of course if you really wanted to complete the task with just destructuring you could simply create some default values like this:

```js
function getVideos(action) {
  const {payload: {videos=[]}={}} = action || {};
  return videos;
}

console.log(getVideos()); // action undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({})); // payload undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({payload: {}})); // videos undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({payload: {videos: [1,2,3]}})); // expected [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have action defined like this `const action = {payload: {videos: ["Matrix", "Star Wars"]}}`

And you can check that payload is not undefined like this `if(action && action.payload)` then you could do your destructing operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a check and a default value without destructuring.

```js
function getVideos(action) {
    return action && action.payload && action.payload.videos || [];
}

console.log(getVideos());                 // action undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({}));              // payload undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({ payload: {} }));  // videos undefined, expected []
console.log(getVideos({ payload: { videos: [1, 2, 3] } })); // expected [1, 2, 3]
```