# Nested object inside JSON in React

Tags: json, reactjs

Sory, I am new here.
I generate `Data` object in ASP .Net Core and it is avaliable through GET `GetData`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ReactImport.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GetPostExampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private Data data;

        public GetPostExampleController() =>
            data = new Data();

        [HttpGet("GetData")]
        public Data GetData()
        {
            return data;
        }
    }

    [JsonObject]
    public class Data
    {
        public Data() =>
            NestedData = new NestedData();
        public int Value { get; set; } = 999;
        public NestedData NestedData {get; set;}
    }

    [JsonObject]
    public class NestedData
    {
        public int NestedValue { get; set; } = 888;
    }
}
```

I can receive this object in my React app and read `Data.Value`, but if I try read `Data.NestedData.NestedValue` I have an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nestedValue' of undefined`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class GetPostExample extends Component {
    static displayName = GetPostExample.name;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.ReadData();
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { ReadData: Object, loading: true };
    }

    async ReadData() {
        const response = await fetch('api/GetPostExample/getData');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ ReadData: data, loading: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Get:</div>
                <div>Data.Value = {this.state.ReadData.value}</div>
                {/*TypeError: Cannot read property 'nestedValue' of undefined
                *<div>Data.Value = {this.state.ReadData.nestedData.nestedValue}</div>*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: received object]

Comment: what is going on, it is not a javascript object/class

Comment: honestly none of what you have posted makes sense. what is Data? What is `NestedData`?  Where does it come from? From your question it looks like Data.NestedData is actually a function and would not give you .NestedValue without calling the function first...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can use a sandbox example in my answer and share it after editing your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors).

```
render() {
    let nestedValue;
    if (this.state.ReadData.nestedData && this.state.ReadData.nestedData.nestedValue)
        nestedValue = this.state.ReadData.nestedData.nestedValue;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Get:</div>
            <div>Data.Value = {this.state.ReadData.value}</div>
            <div>Data.NestedData.NestedValue = {nestedValue}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a valid Javascript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), you may access it like so:

```
this.state.ReadData.nestedData.nestedValue
```

```
const obj = {
  nestedData: {
    nestedValue: 888
  },
  value: 999,
  loading: false
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ReadData: obj
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Get:</div>
        <div>Data.Value = {this.state.ReadData.value}</div>
        <div>
          Data.NestedData.NestedValue = {this.state.ReadData.nestedData.nestedValue}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-59016408-NestedObject]

Comment: It looks like correct syntax, but still not working.
I added {console.log(this.state.ReadData)} (it shows Object with NestedData (which is with NestedValue = 888 inside)).
I also added {console.log(this.state.ReadData.nestedData)} (it shows Object with NestedValue = 888 inside).
But {console.log(this.state.ReadData.nestedData.nestedValue)} gives me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nestedValue' of undefined"

Comment: How can we know what and where you added in your code without any producible example? Also, notice that you can't render a log, you must render a React Node.