# how i solve this ? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'which' of undefined - Material design bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, mdbootstrap, material-design-bootstrap

I'm not well in javascript and css. I'm trying to create login page using template whish is using mdbootstrap. but when i click on "let's go" button i get an error. I  searched for this on the internet. but I couldn't find a solution.

**This is my page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/favicon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    Student Management | Login
  </title>
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/material-dashboard.minf066.css?v=2.1.0" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- pnotify css -->
  <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/pnotifyjs/node_modules/pnotify/dist/PNotifyBrightTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- material icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" />

</head>

<body class="off-canvas-sidebar">
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-absolute fixed-top text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#pablo">Login Page</a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item  active ">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>view_controller/login" class="nav-link">
              <i class="material-icons">fingerprint</i> Login
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navbar -->
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-full-page">
    <div class="page-header login-page header-filter" filter-color="white" style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/login.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: top center;">
      <!--   you can change the color of the filter page using: data-color="blue | purple | green | orange | red | rose " -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 ml-auto mr-auto">
            <form class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>user_controller/user_login">
              <div class="card card-login card-hidden">
                <div class="card-header card-header-rose text-center">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body ">
                  <p class="card-description text-center">Or Be Classical</p>
                  <span class="bmd-form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
                      <div id="statusEmail"></div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                  <span class="bmd-form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password...">
                      <div id="statusPassword"></div>
                    </div>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer justify-content-center">
                  <a href="" id = "submitButton" class="btn btn-rose btn-link btn-lg">Lets Go</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="copyright float-right">
            &copy;
            <script>
              document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
            </script>, made with <i class="material-icons">favorite</i> by
            <a href="http://www.prox.lk" target="_blank">Pro-X Technologies</a> in Sri Lanka.
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url()?>" id="baseUrl">
  <!--   Core JS Files   -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
  <!-- Control Center for Material Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/material-dashboard.minf066.js?v=2.1.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      md.checkFullPageBackgroundImage();
      setTimeout(function() {
        // after 1000 ms we add the class animated to the login/register card
        $('.card').removeClass('card-hidden');
      }, 700);
    });
  </script>
  <!-- custom javascript ----- login page.js -->
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/js/customjs/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- pnotify js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/pnotifyjs/node_modules/pnotify/dist/iife/PNotify.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/pnotifyjs/node_modules/pnotify/dist/iife/PNotifyButtons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my external js file**

```
$(document).on('click','#submitButton',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let password = document.getElementById('inputPassword');
    let email = document.getElementById('inputEmail');
    let endpoint = document.getElementById('baseUrl')+'user_controller/user_login';

    $.ajax({
        url:endpoint,
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{
            email:email,
            password:password
        },
        success:function (response) {

            document.getElementById('inputEmail').classList.remove("is-valid");
            document.getElementById('inputEmail').classList.remove("is-invalid");
            document.getElementById('statusEmail').classList.remove("valid-feedback");
            document.getElementById('statusEmail').classList.remove("invalid-feedback");

            document.getElementById('inputPassword').classList.remove("is-valid");
            document.getElementById('inputPassword').classList.remove("is-invalid");
            document.getElementById('statusPassword').classList.remove("valid-feedback");
            document.getElementById('statusPassword').classList.remove("invalid-feedback");

            if (response.form_err) {
                let form_err = response.form_err;
                if (form_err.email == "") {
                    document.getElementById('inputEmail').classList.add("is-valid");
                    document.getElementById('statusEmail').classList.add("valid-feedback");
                    document.getElementById('statusEmail').innerHTML = "Email is valid.";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('inputEmail').classList.add("is-invalid");
                    document.getElementById('statusEmail').classList.add("invalid-feedback");
                    document.getElementById('statusEmail').innerHTML = form_err.email;
                }
                if (form_error.password == "") {
                    document.getElementById('inputPassword').classList.add("is-valid");
                    document.getElementById('statusPassword').classList.add("valid-feedback");
                    document.getElementById('statusPassword').innerHTML = "Password is correct.";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('inputPassword').classList.add("is-invalid");
                    document.getElementById('statusPassword').classList.add("invalid-feedback");
                    document.getElementById('statusPassword').innerHTML = form_err.password;
                }
            } else if (response == true) {
                // PNotify.success({
                //     title: 'Success!',
                //     text: 'Now you will redirected to the admin panel.'
                // });
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            // console.log(err);
            // PNotify.error({
            //     title: 'Oh No!',
            //     text: 'Something terrible happened.'
            // });
        } 
    });
  });
```

**When i click on the lets go button get error like this:**

```
bootstrap-material-design.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'which' of undefined
    at Object.isChar (bootstrap-material-design.min.js:1)
    at bootstrap-material-design.min.js:1
    at e (jquery.min.js:2702)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2695)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2697)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2693)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:128)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2692)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2697)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2697)
```

How i solve this error? I couldn't find a solution form googling this.

Comment: Have a read of https://codeburst.io/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-in-javascript-c81e00f4a5e3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors Looks like a js error. Maybe use a try catch to assist.

Comment: A couple more issues are the in the ajax call, you are setting the data email and password to dom elements rather than the value of those dom elements. console.log email and password before the ajax call and take a look at them. They are not what you think they are.

Comment: @Spangle I checked that. when i get the value of them problem solved. thanks for the advise. But i cant understand why that error got from mdbootstrap instead of jquery ?

Comment: Glad that helped get things working for you. As for your question, I am not sure, but suspect it is because there was no error with the jquery, thus no error. A suggestion too when looking at your code, would be if using jquery, use it to select dom elements, rather than mix it with vanilla js, and then prefix the variables with a '$' e.g ```const $password = $('#inputPassword').val();```