# Return undefined if object doesn't exist upon checking properties

Tags: javascript

The default behavior is that trying to access a property of an object that doesn't exist is that it generates an error:

```
console.log(organization.name)
```

will generate an error if organization is undefined. Is there a way to somehow change this default behavior and just receive undefined when trying to access a property of a non-existing object? Sometimes it can be helpful rather than remembering to check if object is defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Optional chaining**

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

The **optional chaining** operator `?.` permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid.

```js
const organization = undefined; 
console.log(organization?.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions :

### Using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), or the "I love new features, or I'm using Babel" method:

Though [not supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=optional%20chaining), the optional chaining is the cleanest solution. If you need retro compatibility, you should use Babel or some other transpiler, though.

```js
let organization = undefined

console.log(organization?.name)

organization = {name: "foo"}

console.log(organization?.name)
```

### Using `try / catch`, or the "it works or it doesn't" way:

This solution just attempts to show `organization.name`, or executes the `catch` block if it failed.

```js
let organization = undefined

try {
  console.log(organization.name)
} catch(e) {
  console.log("organization.name cannot be accessed") // We end up here
}

organization = {name: "foo"}

try {
  console.log(organization.name) // We end up here
} catch(e) {
  console.log("organization.name cannot be accessed")
}
```

### Using `&&`, or the "Working our way to the property" approach:

This one returns the value of `organization` if it is falsy (like `undefined`, `null`, `false`,...), or returns `organization.name` otherwise.

```js
let organization = undefined

console.log(organization && organization.name) // `organization` is falsy, it will show its value

organization = {name: "foo"}

console.log(organization && organization.name) // `organization` is truthy, it will show `organization.name`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!