# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue rendering this code in the browser, is there a way I can fix this? If there's more information needed, let me know? I receive the error at the componentDidMount. Is there something I am
doing wrong.

The PostService is posted at the bottom.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostService from '../services/PostService';

class ListPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    PostService.getPosts().then((response) => {
      this.setState({ posts: response.data });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-center">Posts</h2>
        <div className="row">
          <table className="table table--striped table-boarded">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Content</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {
                this.state.posts.map(
                  post => 
                  <tr key={post?.id}>
                    <td>{post?.description}</td>
                    <td>{post?.title}</td>
                    <td>{post?.content}</td>
                  </tr>       
                )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ListPost;


import axios from "axios";

const POST_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/posts";

class PostService {
    getPosts() {
        axios.get(POST_API_BASE_URL);
    }
}

export default new PostService();
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `PostService` file. You're either not exporting or importing your function properly.

Comment: _Does_ `getPosts` return a promise? Seems like not, but without a [mre] it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Can you also share the code of `getPosts` function ?

Comment: import axios from "axios";

const POST_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/posts";

class PostService {
    getPosts() {
        axios.get(POST_API_BASE_URL);
    }
}

export default new PostService();

Comment: You should return the promise in your service method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your `PostService` to;

```
import axios from "axios";
const POST_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/posts";

export default function getPosts() {
  return axios.get(POST_API_BASE_URL);
}
```

And import as `import getPosts from '../services/PostService';` on your `ListPost` class.

Then use the code below. You shouldn't be setting state inside `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}

getData = () => {
  getPosts()
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ posts: response.data });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle errors here
    })
}
```