# Issue with mapping data in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to map data from my nodejs api to angular. I need to convert the '_id' field from mongoDB to 'id' in angular. I am getting an error trying to map and I am not sure why.

This is my service method to get the data:

```
    getAddresses(addressesPerPage: number, currentPage: number) {
        const queryParams = `?pagesize=${addressesPerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
        this.http
            .get<{ message: string; adddresses: any; maxAddresses: number }>(
                `${ORDERS_ADDRESS_URL}/${queryParams}`
            )
            .pipe(
                map((addressData) => {
                    return {
                        address: addressData.adddresses.map(
                            (address: {
                                _id: string;
                                firstName: string;
                                lastName: string;
                                email: string;
                                phone: string;
                                street1: string;
                                street2: string;
                                street3: string;
                                city: string;
                                state: string;
                                zip: string;
                                country: string;
                                notes: string;
                                creator: string;
                            }) => {
                                return {
                                    id: address._id,
                                    firstName: address.firstName,
                                    lastName: address.lastName,
                                    email: address.email,
                                    phone: address.phone,
                                    street1: address.street1,
                                    street2: address.street2,
                                    street3: address.street3,
                                    city: address.city,
                                    state: address.state,
                                    zip: address.zip,
                                    country: address.country,
                                    notes: address.notes,
                                    creator: address.creator,
                                };
                            }
                        ),
                        maxAddresses: addressData.maxAddresses,
                    };
                })
            )
            .subscribe((transformedAddressData) => {
                this.addresses = transformedAddressData.address;
                this.addressesUpdated.next({
                    address: [...this.addresses],
                    addressCount: transformedAddressData.maxAddresses,
                });
            });
    }
```

When I make the request I am getting data back from my service successfully:
{
"message": "Address fetched successfully!",
"addresses": [
{
"_id": "61d5bbe6334f61f04eec36ed",
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
"phone": "123-456-7891",
"street1": "123 Somewhere Street",
"street2": "Suite 23",
"street3": "Building 222",
"city": "Kingston",
"state": "MA",
"zip": "02364",
"country": "United States",
"notes": "Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Proin eget tortor risus.",
"creator": "61c9df529202251a482c8192",
"__v": 0
}
],
"maxAddresses": 1
}

The error I am getting is "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: `addressData` or `addressData.adddresses` is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Comment: You have three d's in "adddresses"...

Comment: @WillAlexander you were correct that fixed my issue thank you. I cannot believe I missed that thank you!

Comment: No worries :-) sometimes we get so bogged down in our code, we can't even read it anymore. Might I suggest you invest in a decent IDE? ^^ They catch that kind of typo and give you a nice red underline (and even some suggestions!)

Answer (score 0):

I changed this:
`.get<{ message: string; adddresses:`
to this:
`.get<{ message: string; addresses:`

and this:
`address: addressData.adddresses.map(`
to this:
`address: addressData.addresses.map(`

Per suggestion from @WillAlexander

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to map one property, use '...' (spread / destructing)

```
this.http
    .get < {
        message: string;adddresses: any;maxAddresses: number
    } > (
        `${ORDERS_ADDRESS_URL}/${queryParams}`
    )
    .pipe(
        map(addressData => {
            addressData.adddresses.map((ad) => ({
                ...ad, // add existing value
                id: ad._id // adds new value
            }))
        ).subscribe((updateAddress) => {
        });
```