# Best alternative for optional chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, optional-chaining

I have the following chaining operator

```
const age = data.student?.age ? data.student.age: '';
```

this works fine in my local machine but seems to have problem in another machine. on further investigation i could understand that node js lower version(i suppose version below 12) doesn't support chaining operator. I understand that i can replace this with if condition like below but would like to know suggestions on what is the best possible alternative for this.

```
function checkAge(data){
  if(data && data.student && data.student.age) {
    return data.student.age;
  } else {
   return '';
  }
}


const age  = checkAge(data);
```

Comment: It is strange that for something that would be a number (`age`) you want to return a string (`''`) when the property does not exist. That seems like a bad choice.

Comment: Of course the best option is to upgrade node, `Node. js 12 will reach End-of-Life status on 30 April 2022`.   Unsupported Node versions is of course a massive security issue.

Comment: "best possible alternatives" is opinion based.

Comment: [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232)

Comment: @Sha Optional chaining alternative way found??

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for code change. You only need to modify [the `target` option in your TypeScript configuration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) and set it to anything ES2019 or below. Then you can use optional chaining in your TypeScript code and the compiler will produce the equivalent code.

The TypeScript code

```typescript
const foo = a?.b?.c;
```

becomes

```javascript
"use strict";
var _a;
const foo = (_a = a === null || a === void 0 ? void 0 : a.b) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.c;
```

when compiled: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3lAXNlAngNwBQJy6WAZkkvALzYD8AdAEathFA)

Comment: Was about to point out optional chaining equalivalent is more than just using `&&`, but your Typescript output is kind of showing it anyway.. :)  Athough you forgot to put the `var _a` bit.

Comment: @Keith actually, my bad. I made a slightly more realistic example that better represents how/when optional chaining is used.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming declaring *age* as *const*, not to polluting scope with intermediate variables, and returning a number even for '0' and empty string in case of undefined are all a must, shorter option that comes to my mind would be following:

```
const age = (d=>(isNaN(d=(d.student||{}).age)?'':d))(data);
```

For less strict approaches, cleaner solution would be:

```
const age = (data.student || {}).age || "";
// In this case, though, numeric 0 would also be returned as empty string.
```

On the other hand, if you need to do this more than a few times, I would recommend to implement a handy *picking* function like:

```
const pick = (target, path)=>path.split(".")
    .reduce(
        (acc,key)=>acc&&acc[key]
        ,target
    )
;
// And then...
const age = pick(data, 'student.age');
```

> For picking approach it would be worth to reduce the number of
> function calls performed by *pick()* function. I just used reduce for
> the sake of brevity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is readability, you could probably try object destructing.
So, your assigment would look something like this:

```
const {
  student: {
    age = ''
  } = {}
} = data
```