# How to fix this TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery, typeerror

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). How do I fix this type error that is occuring with the dagID = result[0].dag_id line

```js
async function accessData(){
    const access = await main();
    const result = access.dag_runs.map(file => ({start_date: file.start_date, end_date: file.end_date, state: file.state, dag_run_id: file.dag_run_id, dag_id: file.dag_id}))
    console.log(result);
    /*await bqConnection()
        .dataset('IPP_SLA')
        .table('sla_table')
        .insert(result);*/
    console.log(`Inserted ${result.length} rows`)
}

function determineCron(result){
    dagID = result[0].dag_id
    job = bqConnection().query(`SELECT * FROM \`np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.expected_sla\` where dag_id = "${dagID}"`)
    cronTime = job[0].cron_time
    var interval = parser.parseExpression(cronTime);
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
}
determineCron()
```

Comment: Before accessing 0th position of an array named 'result', check where result is available or not as well as length should be equal to or greater than 1

Comment: `determineCron` assumes it has an argument (which is an array). OTOH, you're calling the function with no arguments: `determineCron()`. It _can't_ work.

Comment: @Sakil result is defined in the accessData function, and the length is equal to or greater than 1. How would I call result from that function to the determineCron function

Comment: @mbojko how would I make the arguments?

Comment: Choose a title for your question that helps distinguish it from other similar questions on this site.  [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The `determineCron()` function have to take an argument that will be an array!!!

Here are the things you might take into consideration:

- Make sure that `result` type is an array you can use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method of [Array prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to check it
- `result` might be an empty array so `result[0]` returns `undefined`

you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to have fallback id if `result` array is empty:

```js
    dagID = result?.[0]?.dag_id || 0
```

Comment: "It's very hard to say whether result is an array or not" - it's easy, it's undefined: the function is called `determineCron()`.

Comment: @mbojko oh yeah you're right I have to notice that!!!

Comment: Thank you guys so much for this! Just one follow up so I already made a table on bigquery with the cron_time field and there is a type error on the line cronTime = job[0].cron_time how would i call that field

Comment: @JoshAnderson that's happening because the same reason, `job` might be `undefined` or an empty array and if that's not the case then job[0] might return `undefined` or an object that does not have `cron_time` field in it.