# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'history')

Tags: reactjs

i am using **react-router-dom version  6.3.0** . i am getting ***uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'history')*** error .. i tried many ways after that also getting same error please help me out....
this is Search.js file i am getting error when i search for specific item and also url is not changing it remains as it is..

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import "./Search.css";

const Search = ({ history }) => {

  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const searchSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (keyword.trim()) {
      
  
   
 history.push(`/products/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push("/products");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form className="searchBox" onSubmit={searchSubmitHandler}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search a Product ..."
          onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

And

app.js file

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Header  from "./component/layout/Header/Header";
import WebFont from "webfontloader";
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./component/layout/Footer/Footer.js"
import Home from "./component/Home/Home.js"
import ProductDetails from "./component/Product/ProductDetails.js"
import Products from './component/Product/Products.js'
import Search from './component/Product/Search.js'
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Roboto", "Droid Sans", "Chilanka"],
      },
    });


  }, []);

  window.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => e.preventDefault());

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails/>} />
          <Route path='/products' element={<Products/>} />
          <Route path='/search' element={<Search/>} />

        </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Comment: Why are you using "this.history"? Just use "history" since you are passing it in as a prop to your function. Also, I'm not sure that "history" is getting passed in at all. I would try using the "useHistory" hook from react-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using useNavigate hook of react-router-dom v6.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
navigate(`/products/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      navigate("/products");
    }
};
...
```

Comment: My pleasure! I would appreciate it if you could vote my answer up. Thanks!