# JavaScript forEach function: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, api, foreach

I'm having trouble with understanding how forEach function works. I'm trying to get the sender, subject and timestamp keys from an API and populate my html with that information for each email in the inbox. However, I'm getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined ..` error no matter what I tried.

Should I use for loop instead of for Each? What seems to be the problem here?

inbox.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       // Use buttons to toggle between views
       document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
       document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
       document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
});

function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
      // GET the mailbox
      fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(emails => {
        // Print emails
        console.log(emails);
    
        // ... do something else with emails ...
        emails.forEach(email => {
          const sender = emails.email.sender
          document.querySelector("#email-sender").innerHTML = sender;
          const subject = emails.email.subject
          document.querySelector("#email-subject").innerHTML = subject;
          const timestamp = emails.email.timestamp
          document.querySelector("#email-timestamp").innerHTML = sender;
        });
      });
    }
```

inbox.html:

```
<div id="emails-view">
        <div class="frame">
            <div id="email-sender">From:</div>
            <div id="email-subject">Subject:</div>
            <div id="email-timestamp">Time:</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

API response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100,
        "sender": "foo@example.com",
        "recipients": ["bar@example.com"],
        "subject": "Hello!",
        "body": "Hello, world!",
        "timestamp": "Jan 2 2020, 12:00 AM",
        "read": false,
        "archived": false
    }
]
```

Comment: you dont need to write `const sender = emails.email.sender`. you can just write `const sender = email.sender`.
That is what the forEach loop does. It goes through all the items inside of the array, and inside of the loop each of the items will be called `email`. Try `console.log(email)` inside of the forEach loop to see what i mean...

Comment: you should think about used `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, which could be a security vulnerability (people could exploit it to inject code into your website)

Comment: Agree with @Boguz, you need to just change the text, or, at least, to validate your data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 1):

The error is in here

```
emails.forEach(email => {
  const sender = emails.email.sender
  document.querySelector("#email-sender").innerHTML = sender;
  // ...
});
```

You are not using the `email` variable but, instead, you are trying to access an `email` key that does not exists in `emails`, since it is your array.

Assuming that `emails` is your array (just `console.log` it, it should be an array, as expected), what you should do is just

```
emails.forEach(email => {
  const sender = email.sender
  document.querySelector("#email-sender").innerHTML = sender;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you all, I tried `email.sender` in the first place but I got an error `inbox.js:60 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML` I'm assuming it's because the DOM is not loaded yet? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Well, please, ensure that you have a `div` with id `email-sender` in your DOM before trying to change it. I suppose that you need to have a list of emails and not just a single one, so maybe you need to create, for example, `#email-sender-1`, #email-sender-2`, etc instead of just `#email-sender`, and then add your content in the newly created `div`. If that is the case, you may add the new `div` while looping the emails, and then change it. Like "Create the sender div for email with id one and then put inside it the sender value of that email".

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the `emails` variable is an array or something JS can loop through.

If you try to loop through something that JS cannot, then it will mark it as undefined.

I have also noticed that you put `console.log(emails);`
Look at this to see if the `emails` variable even exists (or has data), or if it can be looped through.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).