# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, typeerror

```
  const html = `
        <article class="country ${className}">
          <img class="country__img" src="${data.flags.png}" />
          <div class="country__data">
            <h3 class="country__name">${data.name.common}</h3>
            <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
            <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
              +data.population / 1000000
            ).toFixed(1)}</p>
            <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages[0]}</p>
            <p class="country__row"><span></span>${
              data.currencies[0].name
            }</p>

          </div>
        </article>
  `;
  console.log(data);
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  //   countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};
```

> This is the code to output the data

```
  //country 1
  fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      renderCountry(data[0]);
      const neighbour = data[0].borders[0];

      //if theres no neighbour return immedaitely
      //thats what the ! is for
      if (!neighbour) return;

      //country 2
      return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/${neighbour}`);
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => renderCountry(data[0], 'neighbour'))
```

> this is the code to get the data through promises

> currencies: NGN: {name: 'Nigerian naira', symbol: '₦'}
> And this is the array sample array, im trying to get the 'name'
> i think data.currencies[0].name should work and its not

> if i run the code this way,

```
<p class="country__row">< <span>>/span>${data.currencies[0]}</p>
```

> i get undefined without the real data showing which is the real problem

> if i run it this way,

```
<p class="country__row"><span>< </span>${data.currencies[0].name}</p>
```

> i get this error
> <TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') and i > dont know why

<the main problem here is when i dont add .name when trying to read and output the data and just run data.currencies[0], it gives me undefined and when i try to run data.currencies[0].name it gives me typeerror and i dont think it should be because i think im reading the data correctly.

Comment: you've not really given us enough to go on but it looks like you may have more success with `data.currencies.NGN.name`.

Comment: yes data.currencies.NGN.name works but then im meant to use the api data to get info for other countries too and so using data.currencies.NGN.name is only working for nigeria and not any other country

Comment: well then loop through all of them to display them all. I can't tell you exactly how to do that because I have no idea which framework (if any) you're working in, or if you're generating this as HTML on the server side, etc.

Comment: in any case, this is now a completely different question from the one you asked

Comment: Ive edited the question and added all the neccessary code i think, so you can please help look at it and try to help me understand what the problem is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data returned, `currencies` is NOT an array... But an object. So you can not use `currencies[0]`. You need to know the property name.

Now... You can "know" it using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which create an array with the keys found in an object.
And then use the first array item as a key for the object.

So `Object.keys(data.currencies)[0]` would give you the first key in the currencies object.

```js
const countries = ["nigeria", "brazil", "canada", "france", "italy"]

countries.forEach((country) =>
  fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
  const coutryData = data[0]
  const countryCurrencies = coutryData.currencies
    console.log(`${country}: ${countryCurrencies[Object.keys(countryCurrencies)[0]].name}`)
  })
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i added the Object.keys() method and it finally worked