# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_ansicursor')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

While building application its compile successfully but in browser I am getting this error

```
ansi.js:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_ansicursor')
    at ansi (ansi.js:93:1)
    at ./node_modules/nor-debug/src/debug.js (debug.js:47:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83:1)
    at ./node_modules/fin-id/src/pankkiviivakoodi.js (pankkiviivakoodi.js:33:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83:1)
    at ./node_modules/fin-id/src/index.js (index.js:35:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83:1)
    at ./src/app/common/utils/utils.ts (key-filter.ts:8:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83:1)
    at ./src/app/common/utils/index.ts (index.ts:1:1)
```

**key-filter.ts**

```
export class KeyFilter {

  static allowNumbersAndComma(): RegExp {
    let a: RegExp = /[0-9,]/;

    return a;
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export * from './utils';
export * from './form-utils';
export * from './key-filter';
```

Not able to find anything relevant to this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)