# Getting Data from complex JSON in React.js

Tags: reactjs, json, api, axios

I am trying to access the city attribute using postItem.address.city but its throwing error that city isnt defined

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

above is a sample array of object from the api,
here is how i tried to access the data:

```
 {posts.map((postItem) => (
            <tr key={postItem.id}>
              <td>{postItem.id}</td>
              <td>{postItem.name}</td>
              <td>{postItem.username}</td>
              <td>{postItem.address.city}</td>
              <td>{postItem.email}</td>
              <td>
```

the others attributes are working well except the city attribute

here is the error:

```
Posts.js:43 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')
    at Posts.js:43:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Posts (Posts.js:37:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18610:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203:1)
```

Comment: Can you send through the whole array? Do you know for certain that the `"address"` exists on all of the objects in the `Array`?

Comment: I'd imagine address is null or undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782232/how-to-avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have no city in your incoming address. The modern way to handle that is with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Rather than this:

```
<td>{postItem.address.city}</td>
```

You could try this:

```
<td>{postItem.address?.city}</td>
```

But, that would leave you with an `undefined` message, which isn't nice, so you could do this instead:

```
<td>{postItem.address?.city || 'Unknown City'}</td>
```

Which outputs the string `Unknown City` if the city is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, This worked only that i dont know how to post to the api to return the city attr instead of "unknown city". Thanks in advance